OHLC of first candle in regular session while script is also making pre-market session high and low lines
I'm making a breakout indicator and am using this code using pre-market session. How to get the first candle of the regular session OHLC, not the first candle of the day to use in calculations for lines.
//@version=5

indicator(title='script', shorttitle='script', overlay=true)

//Premarket high and low
t = time("1440","0400-0930")
is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t
ending_hour = 9
ending_minute = 30

pm_high = float(na)
pm_low = float(na)


if is_first and barstate.isnew and (hour < ending_hour or hour >= 16 or hour == ending_hour and minute < ending_minute)
    pm_high := high
    pm_low := low
    pm_low
else
    pm_high := pm_high[1]
    pm_low := pm_low[1]
    pm_low

if high > pm_high and (hour < ending_hour or hour >= 1600 or hour == ending_hour and minute < ending_minute)
    pm_high := high
    pm_high

if low < pm_low and (hour < ending_hour or hour >= 1600 or hour == ending_hour and minute < ending_minute)
    pm_low := low
    pm_low

//variable
td = time - time[5]
pm_calc = pm_low + ((pm_high - pm_low) /2)
pm_new = pm_low + ((pm_high - pm_low) /2)



//Premarket high and low lines
line.new(bar_index, pm_high, bar_index +1, pm_high, extend=extend.none, color=#d50000, width =1)

//plot(pm_high, style=plot.style_line, title='Premarket high', trackprice=true, color=color.new(#000000, 0), linewidth=1)
pmh = label.new(x=time + td, y=pm_high, text='PM High', xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=label.style_none, textcolor=#000000, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)
label.delete(pmh[1])

line.new(bar_index, pm_low, bar_index +1, pm_low, extend=extend.none, color=#d50000, width =1)
//plot(pm_low, style=plot.style_line, title='Premarket low', trackprice=true, color=color.new(#000000, 0), linewidth=1)
pml = label.new(x=time + td, y=pm_low, text='PM Low', xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=label.style_none, textcolor=#000000, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)
label.delete(pml[1])


There is a built-in variable for this. session.isfirstbar_regular.

Returns true on the first regular session bar of the day, false
otherwise. The result is the same whether extended session information
is used or not.

